# Cannot connect to postgres db using docker build

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build an image and deploy it to a VPS.

I am running the app successfully with

```
docker-compose up
```

Then I build it with

```
docker build -t mystore .
```

When I try to run it for a test locally or on the VPS trough docker cloud:

```
docker run -p 4000:8000 mystore
```

The container works fine, but when I hit http://0.0.0.0:4000/

I am getting:

**OperationalError at /
could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known**

I have changed the postgresql.conf listen_addresses to "*", nothing changes. The posgresql logs are empty. I am running MacOS.

Here is my DATABASE config:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

This is the Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.5
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN \
  apt-get -y update && \
  apt-get install -y gettext && \
  apt-get clean

ADD requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8000
ENV PORT 8000

CMD ["uwsgi", "/app/saleor/wsgi/uwsgi.ini"]
```

This is the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
  celery:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: common.env
    command: celery -A saleor worker --app=saleor.celeryconf:app --loglevel=info
    volumes:
      - .:/app:Z
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis
  search:
    image: elasticsearch:5.4.3
    mem_limit: 512m
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:9200:9200'
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    env_file: common.env
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - search
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - .:/app:Z
  makemigrations:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py makemigrations --noinput
    volumes:
      - .:/app:Z
  migration:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py migrate --noinput
    volumes:
      - .:/app:Z
```

Comment: seems like pg and your app are not on the same network. can you post your compose file?

Comment: could you clarify what "it" refers to in your statement: `When I try to run it for a test locally or on the VPS trough docker cloud`?

Comment: After the build I am pushing it to docker cloud and then to the VPS. The app runs and when I enter the url in browser I get the error message. Same scenario on my local machine since it's docker right

Comment: which container are you running with the `docker run -p 4000:8000 [name]`? what is [name] here?

Comment: Just a placeholder for the question. I will edit the question.

Comment: after `docker run -p 4000:8000 mystore`, what containers are running? `docker ps` to see.

Comment: mystore, celery, redis, elasticsearch

Comment: I can make the docker cloud repo public for you to try running it

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `links` to your `web` image

```
web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    env_file: common.env
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - search
    links: # <- here
      - db
      - redis
      - search
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - .:/app:Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the available networks. There are 3 by default:

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
db07e84f27a1        bridge              bridge              local
6a1bf8c2d8e2        host                host                local
d8c3c61003f1        none                null                local
```

I've a simplified setup of your docker compose. Only postgres:

```
version: '2'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    name: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    networks:
      random:

  networks:
    random:
```

I gave the postgres container the name postgres and called the service postgres, I created a network called '`random`' (last commands), and I've added the service postgres to the network random. If you don't specify a network you will see that docker-compose creates its a selfnamed network.
After starting docker-compose, you will have 4 networks. A new bridge network called random.

Check in which network your docker compose environment is created by inspecting for example your postgres container:
Mine is created in the network '`random`':

```
$ docker inspect postgres
```

It's in the network '`random`'.

```
 "Networks": {
                "random": {..
```

Now start your `mystore` container in the same network:

```
$ docker run -p 4000:8000 --network=random mystore
```

You can check again with `docker inspect`. To be sure you can `exec` inside your mystore container and try to `ping postgres`. They are deployed inside the same network so this should be possible and your container should be able to translate the name `postgres` to an address.

Answer (score 0):

in your docker-compose.yml, add a network and add your containers to it like so:

to each container definition add:

```
networks:
    - mynetwork
```

and then, at the end of the file, add:

```
networks:
    mynetwork:
```

Comment: I am getting ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'networks' must be a mapping not a string. However i am looking into networks now :)

Comment: oh, i'm sorry, forgot to put the colon at the end of the network name. fixed now.

Comment: with the suggested changes concerning network, what is the output of `docker-compose build && docker-compose up`?

Comment: docker-compose up works fine. docker build -t mystore . is OK docker run -p 4000:8000 mystore is OK. But when I try to reach https://0.0.0.0:4000/ I am still getting "could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known"

Comment: I can make the docker cloud repo public for you to try?

Comment: when you run the containers by hand, you have to provide the network parameter as an argument like so: `docker run --network 'mynetwork' [...]`

Comment: $ docker network ls returns four results: bridge, host, none and saleor_default The last one is the store app that I am extending.